# RestKit: 0 objects mapped after resetting persistent stores on logout

Tags: objective-c, core-data, restkit

On RestKit version 0.23.x, I'm trying to reset core data's persistent store when the user logs out, using the following:

```
// Cancel all requests
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] cancelAllObjectRequestOperationsWithMethod:RKRequestMethodAny matchingPathPattern:@"/"];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].operationQueue cancelAllOperations];

[RKObjectManager sharedManager].managedObjectStore.managedObjectCache = nil;

// Clear our object manager
[RKObjectManager setSharedManager:nil];

// Reset our persistent store
[[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore] resetPersistentStores:nil];

// This command runs the reconfiguration of RestKit, the same
// code that is applied when the app launches.
[self setup]
```

However, when I log back in, RestKit fails to map responses:

```
2015-01-27 10:28:16.452 <APP_NAME>[80341:12445388] I restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:220 GET '<api url>' (200 OK / 0 objects) [request=0.2098s mapping=0.0011s total=0.2112s]
```

Once I restart the app, restkit correctly maps objects again:

```
2015-01-27 10:33:13.918 <APP_NAME>[80400:12458200] I restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:220 GET '<api url>' (200 OK / 1 objects) [request=0.3969s mapping=0.0332s total=0.4305s]
```

As far as I can tell, I'm resetting and nil'ing the relevant managed object context and fetched results controller:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    // These are lazily instantiated, so will be
    // recreated the next time they are referenced
    _fetchedResultsController = nil;
    _managedObjectContext = nil;
}
```

What am I missing?

More info - with trace logging level, I can see that the server is correctly returning data, but it's not being mapped. (Data is truncated for security reasons):

```
2015-01-27 17:32:03.773 <APP_NAME>[86020:12883038] T     restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:218 GET '<api url>' (200 OK / 0 objects) [request=0.3788s mapping=0.0011s total=0.3802s]:

response.headers={
  Connection = "keep-alive";
  "Content-Length" = 342;
  "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
  Date = "Tue, 27 Jan 2015 16:32:03 GMT";
  Etag = "\"-968344033\"";
  Vary = "Accept-Encoding";
  "X-Powered-By" = Express;
}
response.body={
  "status": "success",
  "data": { <--- truncated exactly one object --> }
}
```

Another edit:
The problem seems to affect (as would be expected) only entity mappings, not plain object mappings (there is one such successful mapping in the login step).

Comment: So you clear various things down to nil, but when do you recreate them?

Comment: Excellent question! I should have been more precise about that. Updating question momentarily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I was overcomplicating the problem. Here's a solution that works for me now:

```
// Cancel any network operations and clear the cache
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].operationQueue cancelAllOperations];
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];

// Cancel any object mapping in the response mapping queue
[[RKObjectRequestOperation responseMappingQueue] cancelAllOperations];

// Reset persistent stores
[self.managedObjectStore resetPersistentStores:nil];
```

To clarify: No need to be nilling anything at all.

Comment: Do you still setup all the RestKit values after that? I have the same code but I get an error from RestKit telling me it can't save my new logged user's data: `Failed saving managed object context to the persistent store`.